# Receiving and sending SMS in one BroadcastReceiver (Android)

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to set up one class for receiving sms and sent status.
This is how my manifest looks for this task:

```
        <receiver android:name=".SmsListener" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="5822">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I get received messages, but don't get SENT messages, is something wrong with my Manifest declarations?

```
      PendingIntent _pendingIntent;
      Intent _intent = new Intent();
      _intent.setClass(ParkingOptionsActivity.this, SmsListener.class); // SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver
      _intent.putExtra("test","test");
      _pendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(ParkingOptionsActivity.this, 0, _intent, 0);
      SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
      sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "test message", _pendingIntent, null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to obtain your `PendingIntent` with `getBroadcast()` instead of `getActivity()`, since you want to send a broadcast to your `BroadcastReceiver`, not start an `Activity`.

In your current code, you can simply change that one line:

```
_pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ParkingOptionsActivity.this, 0, _intent, 0);
```

Furthermore, the `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"` action is not present in the SDK currently, and there is no system broadcast when an SMS is sent. Your app doesn't really need that `<action>` in the manifest entry, since the `Intent` is explicitly targeting your Receiver class.

If you do plan to use that action for something else - e.g., differentiating broadcasts in `onReceive()`, receiving implicit broadcasts from other apps, etc. - then you might consider changing it to use something other than the `android.provider.Telephony` package name, so as not to cause potential unwanted behavior or confusion in the future. Using your own app's package name is the norm, I would say.